# SQL Query - Grouping/Aggregating Across multiple Tables

Tags: sql-server, join, subquery, aggregate

```
select D.[Date], E.emp_name, E.emp_jde, count(C.[agent_no]) calls, count(S.[EMPJDENUM]) sales
from
(select cast([start_date] as date) dte, [agent_no]
from call_table
where [skill_name] like '%5700 sales l%'
and [Agent_Time] != '0'
) C
full outer join
(select [AC#DTE_dt], [EMPJDENUM]
from sales_table
where [ICGCD2] in ('LAWN', 'HORT')
and [CHANNEL]= 'INQ'
and [ITMQTY]>3
) S on c.dte=s.[AC#DTE_dt]
right join
(select [Date]
from Date_table
) D on c.dte=d.[Date] or s.[AC#DTE_dt]=d.[Date]
right join
(select [emp_name], [emp_jde], [agent_no]
from Employee_table
) E on C.[agent_no]=E.agent_no and S.[EMPJDENUM]=E.emp_jde
group by D.[Date], E.emp_name, E.emp_jde
```

---

Date Tables -

[image]

Note:  Not all dates will have both calls and sales.

Additional Tables -

[image]

What needs to be accomplished -

1)  Join and Aggregate calls and sales by Employee by joining the calls table (on agent_no) and sales (on JDE) table

2)  Since not all dates will include both calls and sales - use the date dimension table to ensure all dates are represented

The desired result would look like this -

[image]

The query I wrote executes - it takes so long I just end up canceling the query.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Approximately how many rows in each of those tables?

Comment: The call table will have approx 800k and the sales table approx 400k per year of data.

Comment: Could you include the estimated execution plan please https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the query plan, it is a little tricky, but here are a couple of suggestions that might improve the performance:

1. remove the leading wildcard in `where [skill_name] like '5700 sales l%'`
2. put the `group by` into the subqueries

I have an example here that implements both of those. (Note that I did some reformatting just to try to understand what your query was doing.)

```
select D.[Date], E.emp_name, E.emp_jde, C.Calls, S.Sales
  from Date_table As D
  Left Join (
    select cast([start_date] as date) As CallDate, [agent_no], Count(*) As Calls
      from call_table
      where [skill_name] like '5700 sales l%'
        and [Agent_Time] != '0'
      Group By Cast([start_date] As date), [agent_no]) As C On D.[Date] = C.CallDate
  Left Join (
    select [AC#DTE_dt] As SaleDate, [EMPJDENUM], Count(*) As Sales
      from sales_table
      where [ICGCD2] in ('LAWN', 'HORT')
        and [CHANNEL]= 'INQ'
        and [ITMQTY]>3
      Group By [AC#DTE_dt], [EMPJDENUM]) As S on D.[Date] = s.SaleDate
  right join Employee_table As E 
    on C.[agent_no]=E.agent_no 
    and S.[EMPJDENUM]=E.emp_jde;
```

**Edit**

In order to get a row for each possible combination of date and employee, you will need a cross join of the date table and the employee table.

```
select D.[Date], E.emp_name, E.emp_jde, C.Calls, S.Sales
  from Date_table As D,
      Employee_table as E
  Left Join (
    select cast([start_date] as date) As CallDate, [agent_no], Count(*) As Calls
      from call_table
      where [skill_name] like '5700 sales l%'
        and [Agent_Time] != '0'
      Group By Cast([start_date] As date), [agent_no]) As C 
    On D.[Date] = C.CallDate
    And E.agent_no = C.agent_no
  Left Join (
    select [AC#DTE_dt] As SaleDate, [EMPJDENUM], Count(*) As Sales
      from sales_table
      where [ICGCD2] in ('LAWN', 'HORT')
        and [CHANNEL]= 'INQ'
        and [ITMQTY]>3
      Group By [AC#DTE_dt], [EMPJDENUM]) As S 
    on D.[Date] = s.SaleDate
    and E.emp_jde = S.[EMPJDENUM];
```

Comment: This is very close - what is happening though is if someone has a call without sales or sales without calls for a particular day, it is leaving them out of the results.

Comment: And  this query runs efficiently.

Comment: @user3067478 I have made some adjustments that should return rows even where there are no sales or calls

Comment: When I attempted the adjusted query it told me D.Date could not be bound.  Once I removed the additional from on the employee table, i no longer received that error.

Comment: @user3067478 It seems that this answer was helpful to you since you quoted it in another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40642404/sql-server-where-clause-condition-being-ignored It is best practice in this community to accept answers if they are helpful.