# SQL Server - where clause condition being ignored

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, where-clause, cross-join

For some reason the data condition in the where clause is being ignored - any suggestions?

```
SELECT  D.[Date],
        D.Year,
        D.MonthName,
        D.WeekOfYear,
        E.bu_name,
        E.emp_mgr,
        E.emp_sup,
        E.emp_name,
        E.emp_jde,
        C.calls,
        s.sales
FROM    DateTable AS D
        CROSS JOIN EmployeeTable AS E
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT   CAST([start_date] AS DATE) AS call_date,
                            [agent_no] AS agent_id,
                            SUM(CASE WHEN [skill_name] LIKE '5700 Sales l%'
                                          AND [Agent_Time] != '0' THEN 1
                                     ELSE 0
                                END) AS calls
                   FROM     CallTable
                   GROUP BY CAST([start_date] AS DATE),
                            [agent_no]
                  ) AS C ON D.[Date] = C.call_date
                            AND E.emp_vcc = C.agent_id
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT   [AC#DTE_dt] AS sale_date,
                            [EMPJDENUM] AS emp_jde,
                            SUM(CASE WHEN [CHANNEL] = 'I'
                                          AND ([ICGCD2] = 'L'
                                               OR [ICGCD2] = 'H')
                                          AND [ITMQTY] > 3
                                          AND [EMPBUNCOD] IN ('5044','5077') THEN 1
                                     ELSE 0
                                END) AS sales
                   FROM     SalesTable
                   GROUP BY [AC#DTE_dt],
                            [EMPJDENUM]
                  ) AS S ON D.Date = s.sale_date
                            AND E.emp_jde = S.emp_jde
WHERE   c.calls > 0
        OR S.sales > 0
        AND d.Year = '2016'
```

Comment: That's one messy query.  Did you try doing this? `where (c.calls>0 or S.sales>0) and d.Year='2016' `

Comment: Well first I would be interested in your definition of messy?  I am fairly new to this - if there are improvements that can be made I would certainly love to learn about them...

Comment: I meant it looks complicated.  Besides that, without showing your data structures and providing sample input and expected output, it's kind of hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: As Rick stated, we need more information to help. What results are you getting, what results are you expecting... I'm not sure this query would run at all. Did you intentionally add spaces in the table names? `Date Table` ?

Comment: Your where clause isn't being ignored. You need to understand the order of precedence of your predicates. Add parenthesis where they need to be. I will update your question with this query in something resembling a format that is legible. The "wall of text" queries are impossible to decipher.

Comment: yeah you can probably put a parenthesis around  `(c.calls > 0 OR S.sales > 0)`  then have  `AND d.Year = '2016'`

Comment: you could also move your `SUM(CASE WHEN`) logic to a where clause and just use `COUNT(*)`.. might help if you have indexing..

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer but an example of how you could format this query so you can read it more easily. I also modified your where predicates to accommodate what is almost certainly the issue.

```
SELECT D.[Date]
    , D.Year
    , D.MonthName
    , D.WeekOfYear
    , E.bu_name
    , E.emp_mgr
    , E.emp_sup
    , E.emp_name
    , E.emp_jde
    , C.calls
    , s.sales
FROM [Date Table] AS D
CROSS JOIN [Employee TABLE] AS E
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT Cast([start_date] AS DATE) AS call_date
        , [agent_no] AS agent_id
        , Sum(CASE WHEN [skill_name] LIKE '5700 Sales l%' AND [Agent_Time] != '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS calls
    FROM [Call TABLE]
    GROUP BY Cast([start_date] AS DATE), [agent_no]
) AS C ON D.[Date] = C.call_date
        AND E.emp_vcc = C.agent_id
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT [AC#DTE_dt] AS sale_date
        , [EMPJDENUM] AS emp_jde
        , Sum(CASE WHEN [CHANNEL] = 'I' AND [ICGCD2] IN ('L', 'H') AND [ITMQTY] > 3 AND [EMPBUNCOD] IN ( '5044', '5077' ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS sales
    FROM [Sales TABLE]
    GROUP BY [AC#DTE_dt], [EMPJDENUM]
) AS S ON D.Date = s.sale_date
    AND E.emp_jde = S.emp_jde
WHERE 
(
    c.calls > 0
    OR 
    S.sales > 0
)
AND d.Year = '2016';
```

Comment: adding the parentheses worked - I have tried this.  I chose to leave them off because when using them the time to completion for the query was significantly longer

Comment: It might make it take longer but without the parenthesis the logic of the query is completely different.